# Adding @WebFilter and @Component annotation to Spring Filter

Tags: java, spring

I have a Filter class 'MyFilter' that is registered via `@WebFilter`annotation.In the `doFilter()` I need an object of a `MyBeanClass` that I have created  in my project. If I create this object via new operator, and run the project on tomcat, I see that the filter is registered once and is working fine.

However, When I try to Autowire the object by adding `@Component` annotation above the `MyFilter` class, and then run the project on tomcat, I see that the filter is registered twice.The `doFilter()` is called twice and the second time `doFilter()` is called the object of `MyBeanClass` is not initialized and is `null`. Hence the `NullPointerException`.

I need to leave the dependency injection upto Spring and thus Autowiring the object is needed.The concern is -

1. Why is the filter registered twice.
2. Why is the object null the second time.
3. What is the correct way of achieving this.

Here is the sample code : 
MyFilter.java :

```
@Component
@WebFilter(filterName = "RestFilter", urlPatterns = { "/*" })
public class MyFilter implements Filter {

    @Autowired
    MyBeanClass myBeanClass;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        //this is how I know that filter is registered twice.
        System.out.println("this is init.");  
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (myBeanClass.isValidRequest()) {
            System.out.println("Let this request pass");
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Should not let pass this request");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

MyBeanClass.java

```
@Component
public class MyBeanClass{

    Boolean valid = false;

    public boolean isValidRequest(){
        //some code
    }

    //
    //Other piece of code
    //
}
```

I am new to Spring framework, and have recently started working on a project in Spring. Please correct me if I am doing anything wrong. Or if there is another way of doing this, direct me to right resource.

Comment: It is registered twice because it is once detected by the servlet container, which is an instance unknown to spring and will as such not be auto wired (due to `@WebFilter`). There is another instance registered by spring which will receive auto wiring (due to `@Component`).  Use either one but not both annotations.

Comment: Thanks M. Deinum for the quick reply. I need to register the filter via @WebFilter as a it is the convention being followed in the project I am working in. But then Autowiring will not be achieved.Is there a way to achieve both?

Comment: Don't register it as a `@WebFilter` or don't use auto wiring. If it isn't spring managed spring will not do injection, you would have to inject things manually yourself.

Answer (score -1):

This is because you added `@ServletComponentScan` on your Application class and also used `@Component` on your filter. You can remove either of them.

By the way, if you used `@component`, the `@webfilter` will not work